# Is there a way to default a scale for TouchImageView in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

Like many other users here, I am using the TouchImageView class available at https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

In my app, I am loading images files that come from a service, which I set into my TouchImageView object.  This works great as I can zoom in and pan around my image. However, whenever I click one of my buttons to move to the next or previous image, the image zooms back out to the standard zoom before the next image is displayed.  This is the first issue.

The TouchImageView object returns to its initial zoom level any time another component is updated. Just calling this next line of code on an EditText resets the zoom.

```
imagePageNumber.setText(imagePageNumber.getText());
```

To work around this I attempted to save the current zoom level information before it is lost, and then apply it again after the image has loaded.  I wrote a method called setZoom(float mScaleFactor) in TouchImageView that basically mimics the scaling behavior of the existing onScale method. If I call it directly after updating my image with imageView.setImageBitmap(bm), the image does not scale.  If however I have a click listener on a button, and attempt to scale the after the image has loaded, it will update the scale correctly to the value I had saved previously.  I'm assuming there may be a threading issue with how the image is loading, and cannot zoom instantly after setImageBitmap is called.

Does anyone know of a way to keep the scale from one image load to another?

Answer (score 0):

I met it in other circumstances but the solution may be the same.
Referring to your

```
imagePageNumber.setText(imagePageNumber.getText());
```

and

```
 TouchImageView object returns to its initial zoom level any time another component is updated
```

you have to remember onMeasure() method and translateMatrixAfterRotate() inside it result in the TouchImageView updates. translateMatrixAfterRotate() supports rotation, and if you are not interested in rotation ability of your app, you have just to delete the translateMatrixAfterRotate function and all variables started with "temp.." that store the mobile data before rotation.
It must solve the issue of forced TouchImageView updates you are suffering from.